# Insert a row that doesn't exist via a procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to select the `id` of a `country` from the `countries` table. If the country doesn't exist, I want to insert that country then get the `id` of that country. I want to do this a stored function/procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
    id                      int
                            PRIMARY KEY
                            AUTO_INCREMENT,

    country                 char(2)
                            NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT uq_countries_country UNIQUE (country)
);
```

My attempt at the procedure, but I am clueless as to where I am going wrong. Essentially I am giving a 2 character string, and I should get an `id` back from the procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GetIPCountryId(
    IN  _country char(2),  
    OUT _id int
)
BEGIN
DECLARE _country_id int;


    SELECT
        id INTO _country_id
    FROM countries
    WHERE lower(country) = lower(_country)
    
    IF _country_id IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES (lower(_country));
    END IF;

    SELECT
        id
    FROM countries
    WHERE lower(country) = lower(_country)


END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Do not check. Simply execute `INSERT IGNORE`. If a row exists, this will be ignored else the row will be inserted. Anycase after this the row exists - you may select.

Comment: Please explain what is going wrong.  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use `into` in last select.

```
SELECT
        id into _id
    FROM countries
    WHERE lower(country) = lower(_country)
```

Also, you can use `insert into table select ... where not exists..` instead of `count and insert` logic.

Comment: Doesn't work. It says I have a syntax error near the if statement. I want to use the procedure because I want to understand how to use it.

Comment: You have declared _country_id and also it is input parameter. Use different name for variable and parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you can use these 2 methods

1. use `NOT EXISTS`

```
INSERT INTO countries(country)
SELECT * FROM countries c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM countries c1 WHERE c1.id = c.id)
```

2. use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

   ```
   SELECT * FROM countries
      UNION 
      INSERT INTO countries(country)
      SELECT country
      FROM countries
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = values(id)
   ```

BOTH of these queries will insert the country into the table if the country doesnt appear on table `countries`

Answer (score 0):

You would often use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for the purpose of getting the id from an `INSERT`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetIPCountryId (
    IN  _country char(2),  
    OUT _id int
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _country_id int;

    SELECT
        id INTO _country_id
    FROM countries
    WHERE lower(country) = lower(_country);
    
    IF _country_id IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES (lower(_country));
        SET _id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END IF;
END$$
```

Your code fails because the last `SELECT` has no `INTO`.

However, this is still not the recommended way to handle this logic, because it is subject to race conditions (two users attempting the same insert at the same time).  It is better to attempt the insert and then just fetch the value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetIPCountryId (
    IN  _country char(2),  
    OUT _id int
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO countries (country)
        VALUES (lower(_country))
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE country = VALUES(country);

    SELECT c.id INTO _id
    FROM countries c
    WHERE c.country = lower(_country);
END$$
```

For this to work, you need a unique index or constraint on `countries(country)`.

Note:  Newer versions of MySQL would use an `ON CONFLICT` clause instead of `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.